# Differentiate ln$(100|x|)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I asked to find $\frac{\text{dy}}{\text{dx}}$ for $y = \ln(100|x|)$.
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\text{d}\,\text{ln}(100|x|)}{\text{dx}}  &=& \frac{\text{d ln(100|x|)}}{\text{d 100|x|}} \cdot \frac{\text{d (100|x|)}}{\text{dx}}\\
&=&\frac{1}{\text{100|x|}}\cdot \frac{\text{d (100|x|)}}{\text{dx}}
\end{eqnarray}

I'm not sure how to calculate the derivative of 100$|x|$. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: What is it when x is less than 0? What is it when x is greater than 0? Where is it undefined?

Comment: $\frac{d|x|}{dx}=\frac{|x|}{x}$

Comment: What's $y$ stand for?

Comment: @Moo: is that comment directed to me? The (real) functions $x\mapsto |x|/x$ and $x\mapsto x/|x|$ are identical.

Comment: LOL doesn't $\frac{|x|}{x} = \frac{x}{|x|}$ for real x?

Comment: You could save a few steps if you simplified the function before deriving: $\ln(100|x|)=\ln(100)+\ln|x|$ and using the fact that the derivative of a constant is $0$. You'd also have a better view of what is creating the difficulty you encounter.

Comment: @BernardMassé I'm pretty sure they know the hard part, unless you believe that the asker is having issues with taking derivatives of constants times functions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that

$$\ln(100|x|)=\ln(100)+\ln|x|$$

Thus, derivative is simply given as

$$\frac d{dx}\ln(100|x|)=\frac1x$$

Comment: So "simple". Goes nicely with your username.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I try.  $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: for $x>0$ you need to differentiate $100x$ and for $x<0$ you need to differentiate $-100x$.

At 0 the function is not differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

Remember $${d\over dx}|x|=sgn ( x)$$

Where $sgn$ is the [signum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) function

Comment: I don't know what signum function is

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function

Answer (score -2):

The derivative of ln functions is simply ln(f(x))=f'(x)/f(x)